# problema al agregar una dependencia de una animacion de lottie en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, json

mi problema es el siguente, estoy intentando agregar una animacion con lottie en una activity de android studio, pero al momento de agregar la libreria en el grodle app, recuerdo, me marca sincronizar, se sincroniza pero me manda el siguente error

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be
>   smaller than version 16 declared in library
>   [com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0] C:\Users\DELL
>   LATITUDE.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b503afc1b8e10e866df01e429d2f03d2\jetified-lottie-2.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 16,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="com.airbnb.lottie" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)

Como resultado no carga la activity final, solo el simulador del celular pero no muestra la app en funcionamiento

mi pregunta es la siguiente, necesito actualizar la libreria, o tengo que actualizar el sdk,
o puedo buscar una libreria que sea compatible con la animacion o programa de animaciones, las animaciones son con el programa lottie y se descargan en json, les menciono que actualize el programa de android studio por que se actualizo solo, no tenia planeado actualizarlo, yo ahi entiendo que tengo que buscar una libreria compatible con el sdk version 15 o actualizar al sdk 16, pero tengo problemas con la memoria ram, solo llega hasta 8 G.

gracias por su atencion

Comment: Te lo está diciendo muy claro, esa librería no funciona con el minSdkVersion 15 que tienes configurado en el manifest. La solución la planteas tú mismo: o encuentras otra librería o aumentas la versión mínima de Android que soportas en tu aplicación. Las consecuencias de cada opción? Pues no lo se porque no se cual es tu intención en cuanto a versiones de Android, ni tampoco se si existe una librería para hacer eso con Android 15. Lo que no termino de entender es la relación con la memoria ram.

Comment: gracia me sirvio de algo su respuesta, despeje mis dudas

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller
>   than version 16 declared in library

Indica que la library https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android que usas hace uso de APIs que no son disponibles en el SDK 15, que es con el cual estas construyendo tu aplicación, si revisas el [build.gradle](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/build.gradle) de la library precisamente esta configurada con `minSdkVersion 16`

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/build.gradle

**Si usas esta library, como mínimo para tu proyecto debes usar la versión SDK 16.**

Ya que es poco probable que puedan cambiar la configuración en la Library y si la cambian podría no funcionar adecuadamente, me parece que lo adecuado en este caso para solucionar el problema, dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` de tu proyecto debes definir como mínimo  (`minSdkVersion` ) el API 16:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```